# List<string> взять уникальные значение

Tags: c#, list

```
/кошка/1
/кошка/2
/собака/1
/собака/2
/тигр/1
```

Как сделать чтобы в результирующем списке были только те элементы, у которых значения между /*/ уникальные. 
результат

```
/кошка/1
/собака/1
/тигр/1
```

Есть вариант заюзать Distinct, но он работает по полному соответсвию.

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
    list.Add(1);
    list.Add(2);
    list.Add(3);
    list.Add(3);
    list.Add(4);
    list.Add(4);
    list.Add(4);
List<int> distinct = list.Distinct().ToList();
```

А как сделать чтобы он брал значение между /*/ и выбрал среди них уникальные. Мне кажется надо использовать lambda выражения.

Comment: Если ответ Вас устраивает, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

в `Distinct` можно передать свой "сравниватель на одинаковость" - `IEqualityComparer`:

```
class PartialComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public string GetComparablePart(string s)
    {
        return s.Split('/')[1];
    }
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        return GetComparablePart(x).Equals(GetComparablePart(y));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return GetComparablePart(obj).GetHashCode();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>
        {
            "/кошка/1", 
            "/кошка/2",
            "/собака/1",
            "/собака/2",
            "/тигр/1"
        };

        // "/кошка/1" 
        // "/собака/1"
        // "/тигр/1"
        var result = list.Distinct(new PartialComparer()).ToList(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за грамотный ответ)

Answer (score 4):

Для полноты, вот ещё один метод, короче, но менее эффективно:

```
list.GroupBy(s => s.Split('/')[1]).Select(g => g.First())
```

Comment: не совсем понятно как он удаляет дубли))

Comment: @Radzhab: Ну, `GroupBy` группирует все строки с одинаковым животным в одну группу. Потом из каждой группы мы выбираем по одному «представителю».